# Matching a word followed by a space, followed by three numbers in BASH

Tags: regex, bash

I have an issue that I would imagine is simple but I have spent the past hour trying everything out there.

I'm trying to match a string followed by a space followed by 3 numbers in grep.

```
egrep hello\s\d{3}
```

I have also tried older styles:

```
grep hello[:blank:][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

If I use grep with hello or the numbers in a row independently they work fine, but as soon as you try to combine it with a blank or a space, grep returns nothing.

Comment: BTW, this isn't really matching *in bash* -- grep is an external command, so it behaves the same no matter what shell you use. If you wanted a native solution in bash, that would be using `[[ $string =~ $regex ]]` and `BASH_REMATCH`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Off by two characters (or four, if you count quotes):

```
grep 'hello[[:blank:]][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

If you're determining whether a variable (as opposed to a file or stream) matches, on the other hand, `grep` isn't the right tool; bash has regex evaluation built in:

```
str='hello 123'
re='^hello[[:blank:]][0-9]{3}$'
if [[ $str =~ $re ]]; then
  echo "Match!"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I spent way too much time trying to figure that out.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, I honestly don't know. I've tried to extend my answer to be more comprehensive, but yes, you had a good 8-second lead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `[:blank:]` into a character class.

```
$ grep 'hello[[:blank:]][0-9][0-9][0-9]' file
hello 123
```

**OR**

```
$ grep 'hello[[:blank:]][0-9]\{3\}' file
hello 123
```

`[0-9]\{3\}` would match three or more digits.

**How i know that information?**

```
$ grep hello[:blank:][0-9][0-9][0-9] file
grep: character class syntax is [[:space:]], not [:space:]
```

Comment: Appreciate it, didn't know blank required 2 brackets.

Comment: BTW, I _do_ strongly recommend adding quotes here -- otherwise, the argument could be replaced with any filename matching the expression before `grep` is invoked, or deleted by the shell if the `nullglob` option is enabled.